# SSH2 change a user password

Tags: php, shell, ssh, centos

I've been playing around with SSH and now I need to change a user's password via the PHP's ssh2,

Here's my code:

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, 'passwd test1234');
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$data = '';
while($buffer = fread($stream, 4096)) {
    $data .= $buffer;
}
fclose($stream);
echo $data."<hr/>";

$stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, 'saulius123');
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$data = '';
while($buffer = fread($stream, 4096)) {
    $data .= $buffer;
}
echo $data."<hr/>";
$stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, 'saulius123');
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $data = '';
    while($buffer = fread($stream, 4096)) {
        $data .= $buffer;
    }
    echo $data."<hr/>";
```

However this just make's my PHP script hang, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh2_exec` invokes the command; to send input, you'll need to write to the stream.

That is, `$stream` gives you access to standard input and standard output. So you'll need to write the password you wish to set using `fwrite` on `$stream` before trying to read back the output.

Since you've put the stream in blocking mode, `passwd` is awaiting your input (the password) at the same time your script is waiting for `passwd`. As a result, the script hangs.

Comment: So would I do fwrite($stream, "saulius123 \r saulius123 \r"); to set the password as "saulius123"?

Comment: I believe `\n` (the customary Unix newline) would be correct, and you likely do not want the extra spaces, but I believe that ought to work. (Assuming of course you have root permissions; otherwise `passwd` would presumably prompt for the old password first.)

Comment: Thank you worked like a charm! How would I go about executing VI commands? same way? Also how would I go about replicating <Esc>? Thanks!

Comment: `vi` expects there to actually be a terminal on the other end; I'm not sure whether it will accept not having a full terminal emulator available. Invoking some something like `sed` or `awk` would probably be a better way to do that (or for that matter, reading the file over SFTP, changing it locally, and sending it back -- depending on the size of the file, of course).

Comment: On second thought, it seems to warn but accept input nonetheless. To answer your question, you can send `<Esc>` by sending the ASCII code 27. You can use the escape sequence `\x1b` to do this. (It's still probably not the write approach in general, but it is possible.)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net).  Example:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$key = new Crypt_RSA();
//$key->setPassword('whatever');
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('privatekey'));

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("ls -la\n");
echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
?>
```

The biggest advantage of it over libssh2 is portability.  We use Amazon Web Services were I work and sometimes we move over to new prod servers or dev servers and the most difficult part in setting them up is installing all the PECL extensions and what not.

phpseclib, in contrast, doesn't have any requirements.