# Pass <<EOF as string in PHP ssh

Tags: php, string, ssh, escaping, eof

I am having trouble on passing the following command through ssh2_exec through php, the command is

```
./prog cat <<EOF
a a a 
b b 
c 
d d 
EOF
```

The problem is the first line `'cat <<EOF'`, php take "EOF" as a special word and I want the `'<<EOF'` pass as a normal string.

Is there any possible solution on this?

Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know PHP, so I will give a few possible solutions.

1. Just don't use EOF.

   ```
   ./prog cat <<WHATEVER
   a a a 
   b b 
   c 
   d d 
   WHATEVER
   ```
2. Don't use a here-document, provide stdin by piping from printf.

   ```
   printf 'a a a \nb b \nc \nd d \n' | ./prog cat
   ```
3. Surely [PHP provides some way for you to provide the contents of stdin directly to `ssh2_exec`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10274536/86622) or a similar command?

Comment: Thanks Dave, I seem to make it using this method, will keep posting the testing result

Comment: Thanks Dave, I can run the command successfully through php, thanks a lot, allow me to change this problem to "solved"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "a <<EOF b";
```

That displays "`a <<EOF b`". If PHP was doing anything "special" with <

Idk... maybe it's an issue with PECL's ssh2 extension. Or maybe an issue with the shell you're using on the other end. In either case I'd recommend you use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). If it is an issue with the PECL extension that'll fix it and if it's an issue with the shell you can enable logging and see what exactly is happening over the SSH connection.

Comment: million thanks! I try to use dave's method, using '\n' and pipline '|', it seems work as I expected, I will keep trying this method, thanks all bro!